# How to set or get value from cache in symfony2.8?

Tags: symfony, caching

In my **service.yml**

```
cache:
    class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\PhpFileCache
    arguments: [%kernel.cache_dir%]
```

And in my **controller**

```
$cache = $this->get('cache');

if ($cache->fetch($cache_key) != NULL) {
    // mycode
}
```

My **SilencedError** is

> 1-include(\app\cache\dev\30\446f637472696e654e616d65737061636543616368654b65795b5d.doctrinecache.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: did you have such folder that is in and error?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to fetch an entry without checking if it exists. Use `$cache->contains($cache_key)` before fetching the entry.

As the `PhpFileCache` class extends [FileCache](https://github.com/doctrine/cache/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/FileCache.php) which extends [CacheProvider](https://github.com/doctrine/cache/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/CacheProvider.php) you should check the classes for available functions to create and retrieve cache entries:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function fetch($id)
{
    ...
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function fetchMultiple(array $keys)
{
    ...
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function saveMultiple(array $keysAndValues, $lifetime = 0)
{
    ...
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function contains($id)
{
    ...
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function save($id, $data, $lifeTime = 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I save data to cache $cache->save($cache_key,$data) and my class FileCache , CacheProvider is  exist,  But show error